# Plotting a pairwise difference interval of more than two vectors

Tags: plotting

If I have a 6 vectors:

```
v1 = {-2, -15, -4, -12, -8, -6, -14, -32}
v2 = {5, 12, 3, 5, 9, 32, 12, 8}
v3 = {4, 11, 46, 14, 22, 20, 7, 23}
v4 = {27, 9,30, 35, 36, 12, 39, 5}
v5 = {15, 10, 3, 9, 6, 30, 12, 7}
v6 = {2, 19,30, 3, 36, 12, 7, 13}
```

I want to Plot a pairwise difference intervals (as a line) of `v1 - v2`, `v3 - v4`, `v5 - v6`, in one plot with different colors. I know for the two vectors from previous question. But I can't do it
for more vectors. Thank you for help.

Comment: Please post code in a copyable format, so people can use it immediately without retyping.  LaTeX looks good, but it is not copyable.

Comment: `ListPlot[Substract@@@Partition[allV, 2]]` will probably work if you have all your vectors in `allV` (untested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NumberLinePlot[
 Interval /@ Join[
   Transpose[{v1, v2}],
   Transpose[{v3, v4}],
   Transpose[{v5, v6}]]]
```

[image]

Wrap `Join` with `SortBy`, like `SortBy[Join[...], First]` for example, to sort the intervals by starting value.

You can program the joining part, if you have a large number `n` of vectors defined as `v[1], v[2] ... v[n]`:

```
NumberLinePlot[
 Interval /@ Join @@ Table[
    Transpose[{v[i], v[i + 1]}], {i, 1, n, 2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Description

I am not quiet sure if I am getting the right idea what you are after. So, please see interpretation below.

### Example

**Code**

```
  Module[{
  v1 = {-2, -15, -4, -12, -8, -6, -14, -32}, 
  v2 = {5, 12, 3, 5, 9, 32, 12, 8},
  v3 = {4, 11, 46, 14, 22, 20, 7, 23},
  v4 = {27, 9, 30, 35, 36, 12, 39, 5},
  v5 = {15, 10, 3, 9, 6, 30, 12, 7},
  v6 = {2, 19, 30, 3, 36, 12, 7, 13},
  r1, r2, r3
  },
 r1 = v1 - v2;
 r2 = v3 - v4;
 r3 = v5 - v6;

 NumberLinePlot[ (Interval @ {Min @ #, Max @ #} & @ Sort @ # & /@ {r1,
      r2, r3}), PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: output example]

**Reference**

[Min](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Min.html?q=Min)
[Max](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Max.html?q=Max)
[Sort](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html?q=Sort)
[Interval](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html?q=Interval)
[NumberLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberLinePlot.html)